# Perovskites Solar design using COMSOL

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, perovskites, solar-cells, multi-junction-photovoltaics

I am looking at simulating solar cells using COMSOL software. Majorly speaking we are working on A2BX6 perovskites where we plan to simulate solar cells for different doped versions of the perovskite. However the difficulty here is that because most of the doped versions have not been syntesized yet so we do not have access to various parameters that would be required for solar cell simulation. For example I refered to this video - [COMSOL simulation of PN junction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4Yfa6Al-D0).

Is there any other software or method we can use to simulate solar cells efficiently and easily.

Comment: Any other software like COMSOL (that works using continuum systems) will need the same parameters. You can use an *ab initio* or DFT software to calculate the desired parameter from the atomistic  structure and then add them to your COMSOL setup.